# Detecting when the @ key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to detect when a user pressed the @ key in a text box. I can use JQuery to handle the keyup event like so...

```
$('#target').keyup(function(event) {

});
```

But what do I do from here to test for the @ character? I know I can use `event.which` to get a key code. But in this instance I would need to also check for shift - technically this is not a problem, but I know the @ key can move around with different language settings and I am worried that this may prove to be inconsistent. Maybe I am worried wrongly, and I can rely on it always being `SHIFT + 192`?

Ideally I would like something like the following to allow for easier configuration later on...

```
event.something == "@";
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you watch for "keypress" instead of "keyup"?  That's really the only reliable way to do it (that I know of, esp. due to the variations in keycode mappings).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try checking for `event.which == 64`, as 64 is the ascii of the at sign (not tested, but should work)

```js
$("#target").keypress(function(event) {
  if ( event.which == 64 ) {
    alert("weehee");
  }
});
```

If this fails, you can check after keyup (when user releases key), if the last character he inputted into the text field is a @ sign, and act accordingly.

Shai

Comment: I have effectively gone for `event.keyCode == "@".charCodeAt(0)` so it can be changed using a string value ;)

Answer (score 4):

you might want to use the `keypress` event instead to test for a specific character rather than a key. see: http://api.jquery.com/keypress/